# How can I uninstall SQL Server Express from Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed Windows Server 2008 as my OS, but I dislike the SQL Server Express which it provided by default, so I changed to SQL Sever 2008 Enterprise.

The problem is, I don't know how to remove the SQL Server Express edition. In `Programs and Features` under the `Control Panel`, I can't find the installation of SQL Server Express which was provided with the OS by default. I only see the SQL Sever 2008 Enterprise edition I installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since when does Windows install SQL Server Express by default? Are you talking about Express installed with Visual Studio? If you can't find it in Programs and Features, what evidence do you have that it's even installed?

Comment: Could you be talking about Windows Internal Database? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internal_Database

Comment: Also, see @ShawnMelton 's answer, and my comment to it.  What specific OS version are you talking about here?  Server 2008 doesn't come with SQL Express installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have [Window Small Business Server Edition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508696.aspx) which among other things will install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express during setup.

If you can confirm that is the product you have, which I believe would show up under System Information, then you are stuck with SQL Server Express installation. Like the other products (Exchange, SharePoint, etc) Small Business server is meant to be a complete package and generally not let you remove any of the features. You may find a backend way to "remove" it but you bring the possibily of corrupting the OS installation.

You will basically have to just leave it disabled while you use the Enterprise Edition. However I would keep in mind that there is alot of resources being taken up on the server by those additional features.

Comment: Additionally, Windows Server 2008 and Windows SBS 2008 are very different products, with SBS 2008 being based on Sever 2003, so the distinction is important beyond just the additional features and UI/management consoles installed with SBS.

Comment: SBS 2011 comes with Window Server 2008 Standard Edition.

Comment: It sure does, but is that what the OP is talking about?  Or is he talking about SBS 2008?  (Which is really a variant on Server 2003 R2.) Or SBS 2011?  Or a plain ol', "normal" Server 2008 install disc?  Or something else?  The difference matters, which is all I was trying to point out in my comment... which I maybe should have made to the question, rather than your answer, but, oh well.